# Can a Wi-Fi only iPad use a mobile Hotspot to get Internet access?

Tags: iphone, ipad, network

Since I switched mobile providers, I can no longer use my iPhone as a personal Hotspot. The company doesn't allow it, and I didn't realize how convenient it was until I no longer had it.

I used to connect my iPad (Wi-Fi only) to my personal hotspot. Since I am no longer able to do that, I am wondering if I could buy a mobile hotspot and use it in a similar manner?

I've never really given it a thought as to how all the connections are made between devices. I'm guessing that the iPad + iPhone connection works differently. The iPhone is not offering the iPad a 4G/LTE connection, is it? I'm thinking that since the iPad can't access the cellular network, then it won't work with the mobile hotspot.

Since I am not sure what type of connection the iPhone and the mobile hotspot offer to a another device like a tablet, I'm really clueless as to whether or not it would work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) A mobile hotspot appears as a normal Wi-Fi access point to iPad, irrespective of the source (iPhone, any other mobile or any other device which creates a mobile hotspot). Irrespective of the cellular connection type on your device which created the hotspot, iPad will see it as a normal Wi-Fi access point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely use a mobile hotspot with the iPad. Make sure you get a version that connects with devices over WiFi, and you’ll be fine! (I.e. do not get a dongle that needs to be plugged into USB).

The connection process is slightly different than with an iPhone. It isn’t automatic, so you need to open Settings and look for the hotspot under WiFi and enter the password.

The only thing you’ll miss in comparison to the iPhone tethering is that the iPhone lets the iPad use its GPS for location updates. A mobile hotspot does not in the same manner give access to precise locations. Usually this is not a problem at all, unless you specifically want to use the iPad for navigation (GPS routing / mapping).

Comment: Thank you, It’s disappointing to not be able to use our personal hotspots, but at least there is an alternative,

Comment: @Kim Yes, that’s why the practice is unlawful in some other countries. If you’ve got the information you needed, please mark the answer as accepted.